# javascript array matching to show the unique result

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am new to the javascript array matching.

I have two arrays. each array has the same number of element: 11

```
txtfilename=['txt1','txt6','txt6','txt6','txt7','txt7','txt8','txt9','txt9','txt9','txt9']
content=['apple from one','six trees','cats','happy dogs','healthy fruit','good job','ask question','check safety','stay in the house','good results','happy holiday']
```

in fact, the same position of element in txtfilename is matched the same position of element in content.

for example: the 2nd element in the txtfilename is matched the 2nd element in the content.

however, txtfilename has duplicated element, the element of content is unique.

I have the problem of matching these two arrays. 
I want to display these two array as following:

```
txtfilename: txt1
content: apple from one

txtfilename:txt6
content:'six trees','cats','happy dogs'

txtfilename:txt7
content:'healthy fruit','good job'

txtfilename:txt8
content:'ask question'

txtfilename:txt9
content:'check safety','stay in the house','good results','happy holiday'
```

Comment: (psst... java is not javascript)

Comment: Are you actually using Java or Javascript? You've tagged both

Comment: I am using both of it. more focused on javascript

Comment: The question is about `Javascript` thus you should not add `Java` tag

Comment: OP has made this a java question... everyone eject!

Comment: Ok so you are focused on Javascript but this is a Java question.

Comment: sorry for confuse you, I edit my question.  keep java only

Comment: In Java you could use a MultiValuedMap or a Map<String, List<String>> as a data structure to archieve this.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //Initialising arrays
    String[] txtfilename = new String[] {"txt1", "txt6", "txt6", "txt6", "txt7", "txt7", "txt8",
            "txt9", "txt9", "txt9", "txt9"};

    String[] content = new String[] {"apple from one", "six trees", "cats", "happy dogs",
            "healthy fruit", "good job", "ask question", "check safety", "stay in the house",
            "good results", "happy holiday"};

    //creating a map
    Map<String, String> fileNameWithContents = new HashMap<>();

    //iterating through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < txtfilename.length; i++) {

        //check whether the map contains the txtfilename
        if (fileNameWithContents.containsKey(txtfilename[i])) {

            //appending the new content to the existing content in map
            //Eg: txt6, txt7 and txt9
            StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder(fileNameWithContents.get(txtfilename[i]));
            val.append(", ");
            val.append(content[i]);
            fileNameWithContents.put(txtfilename[i], val.toString());
        } else {
            //adding filename and content to map
            fileNameWithContents.put(txtfilename[i], content[i]);
        }

    }

    // Printing contents of map
    for (Entry<String, String> e : fileNameWithContents.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("txtfilename: " + e.getKey());
        System.out.println("txtfilename: " + e.getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This would do the job

Comment: I am using a hashMap to store the filename asd content (key is filename and content is value). HashMap will not have duplicate keys in it..

I am iterating through the filename array and storing the contest against the corresponding filename.. the tricky part is file name can be duplicated.. do before adding the data to map I am checking whether the map has some data for the selected key.. if there is some value then appending the new value to the value from map. 

hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks @Jobin, now it would be just perfect if you edited your answer and added your explanation there, not just as a comment. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!. I get the idea. However, the result I got was: txtfilename: txt6
txtfilename: six trees

txtfilename: txt7
txtfilename: healthy fruit

txtfilename: txt1
txtfilename: apple from one

txtfilename: txt8
txtfilename: ask question

txtfilename: txt9
txtfilename: check safety

Comment: @Jobin You will need to add 'fileNameWithContents.replace(txtfilename[i], val.toString());' after val.append(contents[i]) to get what the OP wants.

Comment: yes. .  fileNameWithContents.put(txtfilename[i], val.toString()); needs to be added after 
val.append(content[i]);..

It got missed after adding the comments.. Thanks for finding it out

Answer (score 0):

In javaScript you could implement a MapReduce algorithm :

```
var result = txtfilename.map((item, index) => ({"txtfilename": item, "content": content[index]}));
var shift = 0;
txtfilename.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
   if (index < arr.length - 1 && item === arr[index+1])
   {
       result[index + shift].content += ", " + content[index+1];
       result.splice(index + 1 + shift, 1);
       shift --;
   }
});
console.log(result);
// [ { txtfilename: 'txt1', content: 'apple from one' },
//  { txtfilename: 'txt6', content: 'six trees, cats, happy dogs' },
//  { txtfilename: 'txt7', content: 'healthy fruit, good job' },
//  { txtfilename: 'txt8', content: 'ask question' },
//  { txtfilename: 'txt9', content: 'check safety, stay in the house, good  results, happy holiday' } ]
```

Edit :
First, I map textfilename and content in order to obtain an array of objects. Each object has a property txtfilename and content.
Then, because the array is sorted by txtfilename, I compare each object with its neighbourg. If both object have the same key (textfilename property), I concat in the first object the two strings (content proprety) and I delete the second object which has become redundant.

Comment: can u give some explanation?

Comment: I've just edited to provide explanations. Feel free to ask if it's not clear enough. You'll be answered